# Dynamic WebElements-Email-Id and Date in Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using webdriver and I want to handle the following scenario:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//h1[contains(text(),'@')]'))
```

Can anyone tell me how we can locate dynamic web elements (say, a label) like email id (abc@mail.com) and date (19/06/2015) using xpath or any other methods available in webdriver?

I don't want to use either contains or starts-with. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a common identifier for this elements like a class or attribute. Considering you have a common class like:

```
<li class="email">xxx@ifg.com</li>
<li class="email">yyy@ifg.com</li>
```

You can use:

```
result = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.email')
for res in result:
    val = res.text
```